# Javascript slideshow with caption issues

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

So I am having issues with captioning my slide show using a javascript, can somebody let me know as to where I am going wrong. My code stands as this:

JavaScript Document

```
var index = 0;
var titles=[1,2,3,4,5];
var img = document.getElementById("img1");

function moveToNextSlide()
{
if (index >= 5){index = 0}
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName = "movieImages/img" + titles[index++] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
CaptionSlide();

}


function CaptionSlide()
{

if( img.attr("src") == "movieImages/img1.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Up!";
else if(img.attr("src") == "movieImages/img2.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Monsters Inc";
else if(img.attr("src") == "movieImages/img3.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Madagascar";
else if(img.attr("src") == "movieImages/img4.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Finding Nemo";
else if(img.attr("src") == "movieImages/img5.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Ice Age";
}
```

HTML document

```
<div class="slides">
    <img id="img1" src="">
</div>
<input type="image" src="images/Next.png" id="button" onClick="javascript:moveToNextSlide()" title="Next" >
<div id ="captionbar"></div>
```

Also to note, that I get this error within the "inspect element":
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null

REVISED

```
var index = 0;
var titles=[1,2,3,4,5];
var img = document.getElementById("img1");

function moveToNextSlide()
{
if (index >= 5){index = 0}
img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName = "movieImages/img" + titles[index++] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
CaptionSlide();

}

function CaptionSlide()
{
    window.onload = function(){
    if( img.src === "movieImages/img1.jpg")
    document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Up!";
    else if(img.src === "movieImages/img2.jpg")
        document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Monsters Inc";
    else if(img.src === "movieImages/img3.jpg")
        document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Madagascar";
    else if(img.src === "movieImages/img4.jpg")
        document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Finding Nemo";
    else if(img.src === "movieImages/img5.jpg")
        document.getElementById("captionbar").innerHTML="Ice Age";
    }
}
```

The HTML Remains the same as before.
No error references however function does not write the text whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `img.attr('src')` by `img.src=="your image name"`.

For example:

```
img.src=="movieImages/img1.jpg"
```

As you are using pure JavaScript,you cannot use `attr()` which is method of `JQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have made the changes however I still get the same error message. What else can I do ?

Comment: How you will get same message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null as you have removed attr('') from your code

Comment: Sorry, I should have said similar error message. The message is the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null.

Comment: Do you run your script after the DOM is ready ? If not, this is probably why your `img` variable is empty

Comment: Hi @Paul, how do I ensure or check that I am running the script after the DOM is ready?

Comment: I edited my anwser to your original post to explain how to do this. Please tell me if you run into any trouble

Answer (score 1):

`attr()` is a method brought by JQuery. If you are not using JQuery, you should keep using `img.src`. Another thing I noticed that might cause trouble : when you read `.src` from your image, you get the full path as a return (including your domain).
Your conditions would then become :

```
img.src === "http://yourdomain.com/movieImages/img1.jpg"
```

( And I just checked to be sure : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp mentions that the return value of `img.src` includes protocol and domain )

Also I think you should **either** define your function `CaptionSlide` inside `moveToNextSlide` so that it gains access to the updated `img` variable **or** not declare your `img` variable inside the `moveToNextSlide` function (so that the global variable gets updated instead)

**Another point** : you should make sure the DOM is loaded before querying elements from it (such as `img`) . To do so, wrap your code in a function, and assign it to the `window.onload` event :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var index = 0;
    var titles=[1,2,3,4,5];
    var img = document.getElementById("img1");

    function moveToNextSlide()
    {
        ...
    }

    function CaptionSlide()
    {
        if( ... )
        ...
    }

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', moveToNextSlide);
}
```

and HTML for button :

```
<input type="image" src="images/Next.png" id="button" title="Next" />
```

Comment: Hi @Paul again, I have seen your previous comment and made the following changes as shown before. Is this the way the window.onload should be written?
Also to note, I do not get any error messages however the function CaptionSlide() does not do anything. i.e. no text is displayed.

Comment: Please note I also updated the first part of my answer. Your conditions should be updated to : `img.src === "http://yourdomain.com/movieImages/img1.jpg"` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I get an error Uncaught ReferenceError: moveToNextSlide is not defined. I am on the verge of giving up, what is another alternative to captioning my images from slideshow?

Comment: Ok, I'm not giving up anyway :) Again I edited my answer (one line added to JS and modified HTML). However, if you want to make your life easier when doing JavaScript, you should consider using JQuery (http://jquery.com/), which is a very popular JavaScript library that solves several of the problems you encountered here.

Comment: Hi, I've completely changed the javascript and the approach to captioning the slideshow. Instead, I have made use of a thumbnail gallery, and when on hover a caption appears by playing with the z-indexes.. this works fine, but now i need to either create a javascript or jquery to change the image in the slideshow with the respected thumbnail image. Although, i have not solved this problem, your advice has not gone to waste, so much is appreciated.